# Error when trying to execute two onclick actions on the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have a little problem here, and if someone could help me, I will truly appreciate.

I have a menu that opens when I click on a div, and once open, I want to close the menu clicking again on te same div. The problem is that I can open the menu but I can't close it.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menuResp").click(function () {

        $('#profile_menu').css('margin-left','0px');
        $('#menuResp').css('margin-left','315px');
        $('#menuResp').attr('id', 'menuResp2')

    });


    $("#menuResp2").click(function () {

        $('#profile_menu').css('margin-left','-300px');
        $('#menuResp2').css('margin-left','0px');
        $('#menuResp2').attr('id', 'menuResp')

    });
});
</script>

<div id="menuResp">
    <ul id="menuRespCss">
      <li class="icon-css">
        <a>Menu</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone have an idea of why this doesn't work?

Comment: `$('#menuResp2').attr('id', 'menuResp')` - Don't do this. Add/remove classes instead, `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code is doing is setting callbacks **at the moment, when the initial DOM is being built**. Of course, there is no #menuResp2 yet. Insdead, set the callback on the document element (or body, or some other parent element), specifying the selector of your menu - this element will fire the event. This will work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "#menuResp", function () {

        $('#profile_menu').css('margin-left','0px');
        $('#menuResp').css('margin-left','315px');
        $('#menuResp').attr('id', 'menuResp2')

    }).on('click', "#menuResp2", function () {

        $('#profile_menu').css('margin-left','-300px');
        $('#menuResp2').css('margin-left','0px');
        $('#menuResp2').attr('id', 'menuResp')

    });
});
```

But. I would stroungly recommend **not to change the ID** attribute, but to work with classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the click handler like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#menuResp', function(){
        $('#profile_menu').css('margin-left','0px');
        $('#menuResp').css('margin-left','315px');
        $('#menuResp').attr('id', 'menuResp2');
});
```

`.click()` only works for elements that are already created, using `.on()` will cover elements that will be created later.

you should really be identifying the element by class though , and using `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` like the comment suggest

Answer (score 0):

just use toggle.   if the item is closed, it will open,  if its open,  it will close.   all the answers above do not check to see if the item is open already or not.

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#menuResp').toggle();
    $("##menuResp2").toggle();
})
```

easier would be to give element a single class and just toggle once on class name, rather than changing the ID of the item,    this second item would not have an avent binding added to it.   But at the same time.   You dont need the ID when you can just toggle with class.   like so:

```
$(".clasname").toggle();
```

this will open any element that is closed with the class of clasname.    this will also, at the same time, close all elements that have that class name, and are also open